# Fade out transition for images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

I'm using the following code to create a range slider, where, each value of the slider would show a different image.

Now, I'd like to add a sort of transition, where images would fade out once the slider value changes. How could I do it?

Thank you all

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;

  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/" + this.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/1" alt="" id="img">
</div>
```

Comment: did my answer helped you?

Comment: nope. I don't see where the transition bit is.

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement before and used this code, you can tune this as per the need.

```js
var imageUrl = new Array();

        imageUrl[0] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg';

        imageUrl[1] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg';

        imageUrl[2] = 'http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg';

        imageUrl[3] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg';

        imageUrl[4] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg';

        imageUrl[5] = 'http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg';
       
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="5" step="1" />
<br /><br />
<img src="" style='width:100px;height:100px;' id='img'/>
slider value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I've added some CSS to handle the transition, and in order for it to be smooth in case the user slides quickly, I set a timeout which changes the src to the new image, and resets each time there is a change (so only one change can be scheduled). When the image loads, we fade it back in.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");
var img = document.getElementById("img");

var loadOutTimeout;    

var loadHandler = function(e) {
  img.classList.remove("fade-out");
  img.classList.add("fade-in");
}

img.addEventListener("load", loadHandler);

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  img.classList.remove("fade-in");
  img.classList.add("fade-out");
  var imgVal = this.value;
  clearTimeout(loadOutTimeout);
  loadOutTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/" + imgVal);
  }, 200);
}
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fade-out {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fade-in {
    animation: fade-in 0.2s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade-out {
    animation: fade-out 0.2s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/1" alt="" id="img">
</div>
```